# Unable to find classpath/URL for Resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not able to find the file/classpath for my xml file. I have tried the absolute path and springs `classpath*:`

```
ApplicationContext ctx =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();



private Resource resource = this.ctx.getResource("classpath*:validation.xml");
```

In the constructor I have:

```
public Validator() {

    if(this.resource.exists()){
        System.out.println("FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+resource);
    }else{
        System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
    }

    this.runInputStream();
}
```

The above prints out out `FALSE` in the console.
[image]

I have the `validation.xml` file in two places just under different names. I am trying to figure out where and why it is not loading or being found.

I posted the project on GIT.... [GitHub Link](https://github.com/drewjocham/commonsIssue.git)

---------------------Update 1---------------------------

I have added the following to my `pom` file:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

It appears to have found/been initialized but the class is not and it gives me a null pointer exception just like it was doing before.

Updated Code:

```
@Configuration
public class Validator {

    private InputStream forms;
    private ValidatorResources resources;

    private Resource validationResource;

    ApplicationContext ctx =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        validationResource = ctx.getResource("classpath*:validation.xml");
    }

    public Validator() {

        this.runInputStream();
    }

    private void runInputStream(){
        try{
            this.forms = this.validationResource.getInputStream();

            this.resources = new ValidatorResources(this.forms);

        }catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in Validator.Class-----runInputStream IOException: "+ex);
        }catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in Validator.Class-----runInputStream SAXException: "+e);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in Validator.Class-----------"+e);
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say. To help debug, you can view the fully qualified path that is being resolved. Try `appContext.getResource("classpath*:validation.xml").getURI().getPath();` to see the full path that is being resolved.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider in the debugger it fails because it is unable to resolve the URL. I have tried absolute path and springs way. You mention way `appContext`, that I did know what class you were referring too.

Comment: I would guess the app context isn't initialized since you're retrieving it with `new`. What happens when you `@Autowired` `ApplicationContext ` ?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider `System.out.println(applicationContext.getResource("classpath:validation.xml").getURI().getPath());` Returns a null pointer exception. And `@PropertySource("classpath*:validation.xml")` will return no such file exists. I do not understand!

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I post it on GIT https://github.com/drewjocham/commonsIssue.git

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider added a bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is you're trying to acquire resources at the field level. In other words, this:

```
public class SomeClass{
   ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
   private Resource resource = this.ctx.getResource("classpath:validation.xml");
}
```

Would make me think that application context isn't fully initialized.

After pulling down your project and checking, my assumption was correct. `ApplicationContext` isn't fully initialized until after the classes are initialized. To get around this fact, you can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation. Your class will now look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Validator {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private Resource validationResource;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        validationResource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath*:validation.xml");
    }
```

On a side note, I'd recommend you take some time to properly configure your pom. Ideally, someone should be able to pull down your code, build, and run. It took me a while to get your project running locally due to manual configuration.

Comment: It appears to have found/been initialized but the class is null, I updated my post. My apologies for the configuration issue.

Comment: That is a different issue... I think you should open a new question describing `validation.xml` and the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **src/main/resources/validation.xml**  is not packaged into the war file.

Replace the < build> section in the pom with this:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

This way the default resource directory for all Maven projects which is src/main/resources will end up in target/classes and in WEB-INF/classes in the WAR.

Comment: `Error in Validator.Class-----------java.lang.NullPointerException` still. Did you pull my project on GIT

Comment: That's another problem...in your version it prints "NOT FOUND' right?...in my it prints "FOUND".

Answer (score 1):

First remove the trailing / in resources part. The resource part should be relative to the build directory.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Next modify your Validator.java

```
@Configuration
public class Validator implements InitializingBean {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("validation.xml");
        if(this.resource.exists()){
            System.out.println("FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+resource);
        }else{
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
        }
    }
```

See [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) for more details. The other approach is to use ApplicationContextAware like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Validator implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:validation.xml");
        if(this.resource.exists()){
            System.out.println("FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+resource);
        }else{
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
        }
    }
```

Build the project then deploy the war in tomcat. You should see something like

```
22-May-2017 10:57:38.658 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml]
FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!class path resource [validation.xml]
```

Comment: You do not need `@Autowired` when using `ApplicationContextAware`. Spring will use the setter method to set the field.

Comment: It appears to have found/been initialized but the class is null, I updated my post

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ChristopherSchneider. I forgot to remove it when I was doing copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("validation.xml");
```

If having a `URL` would be usable to then get a `Resource` from.  It will return null if no resource is found.